# Streaming s3 private videos

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, video-streaming

We have s3 bucket in aws, with videos in it. We need to stream those videos using AWS iOS sdk.

So far the only option I could find was streaming using URL.(for public videos)

But what about s3 getOBject request - I can download the videos and then view it, but is there a way to download in chunks an view it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a way to do it, you generate secure URL to access

```
S3GetPreSignedURLRequest * request = [[S3GetPreSignedURLRequest alloc] init];
request.key = fileName;
request.bucket = self.bucket;
[request setExpires:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600]];
```

This only works on AWSIOSSDK 1+ not 2

Comment: I know this is old but anyway. I can see the object get created where are you getting the url from?

Comment: Could you clarify what object?

Comment: I figured it out. After you create the presignedurl request i have to use ``` [[[AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder defaultS3PreSignedURLBuilder] getPreSignedURL:request]```. The block returns an AWTask which is the url that has been generated. Im stil not done with it yet but i think thats the way to go

Comment: This is the function i read on amazon to call <code>[[[AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder defaultS3PreSignedURLBuilder] getPreSignedURL:request]
             continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
                 
                 if (task.error) {
                     NSLog(@"Error: %@",task.error);
                 } else {
                     
                     NSURL *presignedURL = task.result;
                     NSLog(@"download presignedURL is: \n%@", presignedURL);
                     
                 }
                 return nil;
             }];
</code>

Comment: I am getting this error - Use of undeclared identifier 'AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder'. @AndriusSteponavičius can you please help in this?

Comment: With the help of "PreSignedURLRequest," yes, you can view the content for a short period. What if it's a long video up to 100 minutes? It means if we do that, anyone would be able to download videos not like Netflix, how they do in chunks (blob), I assume. I am not sure how to achieve this with S3.

Answer (score 3):

I help maintain the AWS SDK for iOS.

The SDK supports ranges on the get request so you can download chunks of data in discrete operations.

```
S3GetObjectRequest *getObjectRequest = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:FILE withBucket:BUCKET];
[getObjectRequest setRangeStart:START rangeEnd:END];
[s3 getObject:getObjectRequest];
```

The SDK also contains a delegate protocol that could be used to process data as it is downloaded in a streaming fashion.

[AmazonRequestDelegate protocol](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AmazonRequestDelegate.html)

Answer (score 0):

getObject is by default a non-blocking download call. So basically the framework is designed to handle a callback once the download is complete to give you the data in the output stream and feed it to the client stream for viewing.

SDKs supports non blocking downloads so ideally you'd download in chunks at the client side as well.